# Mocking css modules in jest

Tags: css, jestjs

In my test I am importing a **jsx** file which imports **css**:

```
import styles from '~/shared/styles/Profile.css';
```

I am trying to mock all css files with **identity-obj-proxy** as I am using **css-modules**. It doesn't seem to work though.

**Package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper":{
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
```

I also tried:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper":{
      "^.+\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/config/CSSStub.js"
    },
```

while creating **CSSStub.css**

```
module.exports = {};
```

No effect - still the same parsing css error from Jest.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're still having this since the question is around 6 months old but I think you should name your file `CSSStub.js` instead of `CSSStub.css`.

Answer (score 1):

identity-obj-proxy doesn't work with default export.

Comments in this issue helps me. https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy/issues/8

Especially joaovieira's comment seems good.

Here is alternative implementation for identity-obj-proxy, that works with default export.

https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy/issues/8#issuecomment-430241345

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy/issues/8#issuecomment-624786468) (adding a type definition for css module files) was what solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

this solved the problem for me

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.(sass|css)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styles.js'
  }
```

error:

```
    Cannot find module 'myStyles.module.sass' from 'myComponent.js'
```