# Mock css-modules in Jest snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, css-modules

I have a problem with creating snapshot test for my component. I followed many anwsers like:

- [Mocking css modules in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706652/mocking-css-modules-in-jest)
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1347
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack

But none of the solutions work for me (maybe it is because my files are in TypeScript not JS but I have no idea).
My component is `UploadFile.tsx` :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import css from './UploadFile.scss';

interface Props {
  uploadFile(data: FormData): void;
  resetUploadedCsv(): void;
}

export class UploadFile extends React.Component<Props> {
  public handleUploadFile = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.props.resetUploadedCsv();
    const data = new FormData();
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    data.append('file', file);
    this.props.uploadFile(data);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label className={css.uploadButton}>
          Upload
          <input
            id='Upload'
            type='file'
            accept='.csv'
            onChange={this.handleUploadFile}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my test is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { UploadFile} from '../UploadFile';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const fakeProps = {
    uploadFile: (data: FormData) => console.log(data),
    resetUploadedCsv: () => console.log('reset'),
  };
  const tree = renderer.create(<UploadFile{...fakeProps} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploadButton' of undefined

I tried to use `jest-css-modules` library and then in package.json:
      `"\\.(css|less|scss|sss|styl)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules"`

I tried to use `identity-obj-proxy` as well as many combinations in `moduleNameMapper`. None of the solutions from the links above work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set `--esModuleInterop` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.test.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  ...
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score -2):

As you are using TypeScript your import is wrong, should be:

```
import * as css from './UploadFile.scss';
```